# Finding max Int in array List. But need to print out users name?

Tags: java, arrays, list

New programmer here... I am writing a program that gets a user's name as the input(String), followed by score (Int). Then i am storing them in to an array's list. I am trying to find the user who has got the highest score? I need to print out there name but not to sure how to do it. Here is what i have so far.

The arrays list this information is stored in is 'people'. Thank you!

```
public String top()
{
    String top;
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for(int i=0; i<people.size(); i++){
        if(people.get(i).getMark() > max){
            top = people.get(i).getName();
        }
    }


    return top;
}
```

Comment: Please do not remove the question body.  It exists for other people to find it and be helped by it in the future.

Comment: DO NOT do what you just did to your question. You can't just change it to "problem solved" once it's solved. Leave your question as is, and just *accept* the right answer.

Answer (score 3):

You are forgetting to set `max = people.get(i).getMark();` just before the `if`-statement closes.

Comment: @user3023003 your code wouldn't even compile even with this answer as help.

Comment: That is because i did not include the rest of the code, there are other classes...Also the arrays list is not shown there.

Comment: @user3023003 Please consider accepting an answer for your question, because it seems like your question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

Store the index of the max instead of the maximum value itself. You can figure out the max value from its index.

You can then use the index at the end to figure out the name.

Answer (score 0):

Have your `people` `Collection` be parametrized with a custom `Person` or `User` class that implements `Comparable` based on its `score` property.

Full example below (assuming this code is within a `Main` class):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<User> people = new ArrayList<User>();
    people.add(new User("user3023003", 1));
    people.add(new User("Chuck Norris", Integer.MAX_VALUE));
    System.out.println(Collections.max(people).name);
}

static class User implements Comparable<User> {
    String name; 
    int score;
    User(String name, int score) {
        this.name = name;
        this.score = score;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(User other) {
        if (other == null) {
            return -1;
        }
        else {
            return ((Integer)score).compareTo(((User)other).score);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Chuck Norris
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get an error because you have not initialized `top` and there is a chance that it will not have a value. That's the first thing you *should have* mentioned in your question.

Secondly, you are not changing the `max` value once you find one that is larger than the one previously recorded. Change your code to this:

```
public String top()
{
    String top = people.get(0).getMark(); // initialize it to one of the marks
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for(int i=0; i<people.size(); i++){
        if(people.get(i).getMark() > max){
            top = people.get(i).getName();
            max = people.get(i).getMark(); // update the max value
        }
    }
    return top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to reinvent the wheel in regards to finding the highest score in the list.  Take advantage of [the APIs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max%28java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Comparator%29)!

Something like this will work (assuming your class is named `Person`):

```
Person maxMark = Collections.max(people, new Comparator<Person>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(Person arg0, Person arg1) {
        return arg0.getMark() - arg1.getMark();
    }
});

System.out.println("Person with highest mark: " + maxMark.getName() + ": " + maxMark.getMark());
```